# What is the minimum sized wrist the Apple Watch can fit?

Tags: apple-watch

I am interested in getting the Apple Watch, the only problem is I have small wrists so I am not sure if the Apple Watch will fit my wrist even if I choose the 38mm (small) one.

What is the smallest sized wrist the 38mm Apple Watch can fit? (I presume the 38mm is the largest wrist the watch fits?)

Comment: You asked "I presume the 38mm is the largest wrist the watch fits?"... That numeric designator has little to do with the circumference of one wrist as to whether or not it will fit.  After all there is only a 4 mm difference between the two sizes heights. (Actually 3.4 mm).  As noted in the answer below it has more to do with the actual Band  and its size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specified on [Apple's Watch Case and Band Sizes page](http://www.apple.com/shop/watch/sizing-guide), the smallest band (therefore fitting the smallest size wrist) is the Classic Buckle, which fits a 125mm wrist circumference.

The next size of bands, are the ones that fit 130mm wrist circumferences:

- Milanese Loop (130-180mm)
- Classic Buckle (125-200mm)
- Sport Band (130-180mm and 150-200mm)
- Woven Nylon (125-195mm)

Keep in mind these are sizes for the 38mm Apple Watch. 42mm band sizes are a bit larger, starting at 140mm for the Link Bracelet and Sport Band, and 145mm for Woven Nylon.